# Should [aci] be a synonym of [azure-container-instances]?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was using [aci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aci) but realized that [azure-container-instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-container-instances)
is essentially the same (?) and 10 times bigger in questions volume.
Should they be merged? They are currently unrelated.

`[aci]` is older but with less examples and less well documented (and not belonging to the `[azure-*]` group.

Comment: They are *absolutely* referring to the same thing. Any reason we shouldn't just manually run through the 14 questions with [tag:aci] and retag?

Comment: Retagged obvious candidates which seemed still valid (including a couple with *both* tags); close-voted the off-topic/broad/unreproducable ones (IMO).

Comment: @PaulRoub "any reason we shouldn't" ... quite a few actually. 1. because it just is excess manual work when a moderator can do the retag using one button 2. because there won't be a synonym added at the end of the manual work, which might result in the tag being recreated at some point of time in the future. 3. because it just bumps the old posts to the front page (just a minor reason).

Comment: This is now done… Unfortunately, it looks like someone took @Paul’s suggestion and made a bunch of manual edits. There were only half as many questions left with the [[tag:aci]] tag. I really wish people would stop trying to do retagging manually when all that’s needed is a simple one-click merge...